# How do I corrupt InnoDB tables in mariaDB and also how to check if the tables are corrupted?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I am trying to learn about mariaDB and a storage engine-innoDB.
I want to learn how to corrupt innoDB tables and recover them back.

Comment: *"How do I corrupt InnoDB tables in mariaDB"* opening the table file in a hex editor and write a few raw bytes randomly in that file and or at the start of that file where the "header" is.. i am pretty sure that would get a table corrupted at some point

Comment: Thank you @raymond nijland.  Could you help me know which file needs to be written. Is it '.ibd' or '.frm' file?

Comment: be awarnt, innoDB can use one `.ibd` for all tables depening on settings, so you might be corrupting all tables.. *"Could you help me know which file needs to be written"* The explainment is to much to explain it in detail.

Comment: But generally MySQL directly maps database names as a disk directory and table names as a disk files within that disk directory under the MySQL data dir..

Comment: You might like to read: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-tablespaces/